# Credential changeset not inserted into database

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

When I create a new user I go through the following process,

**accounts.ex**

```
def register_user(attrs \\ %{}) do
    %User{}
    |> User.registration_changeset(attrs)
    |> Repo.insert()
end
```

**user.ex**

```
def changeset(user, attrs) do
    user
    |> cast(attrs, [:name, :username])
    |> validate_required([:name, :username])
    |> validate_length(:username, min: 1, max: 20)
    |> unique_constraint(:username)
end

def registration_changeset(user, params) do
    user
    |> changeset(params)
    |> Ecto.Changeset.cast_assoc(:credential, with: &Credential.changeset/2)
end
```

**credential.ex**

```
def changeset(credential, attrs) do
    credential
    |> cast(attrs, [:email, :password])
    |> validate_required([:email, :password])
    |> validate_length(:password, min: 6, max: 100)
    |> unique_constraint(:email)
    |> put_hash()
end

defp put_hash(changeset) do
    case changeset do
      %Ecto.Changeset{valid?: true, changes: %{password: pass}} ->
        put_change(changeset, :password_hash, Bcrypt.hash_pwd_salt(pass))
      _ ->
        changeset
    end
end
```

When testing this I get the following,

```
iex(0)> Accounts.register_user(%{name: "Test", username: "test", email: "test@here.com", password: "12345678"})
[debug] QUERY OK db=17.2ms queue=1.7ms
```

While trying to view the user though I notice that the *Credentials* table is empty,

```
iex(1)> Repo.all User
[debug] QUERY OK source="users" db=1.5ms decode=0.1ms queue=0.2ms
[    
  %App.Accounts.User{
    __meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "users">,
    credential: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :credential is not loaded>,
    id: 1,
    inserted_at: ~N[2019-06-21 16:39:46],
...
]

iex(2)> Repo.all Credential
[debug] QUERY OK source="credentials" db=5.5ms queue=0.1ms
[]
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Looks like you're hitting your default case in your `put_hash` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cast_assoc` requires one more level of nesting.

In your example, `cast_assoc(:credential, ...)` tries to find `credentials` key in your params, and params **under** that key will be tried to be cast as `Credential` changeset.

Here is an example from the [docs](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#cast_assoc/3):

```
%{"name" => "john doe", "addresses" => [
  %{"street" => "somewhere", "country" => "brazil", "id" => 1},
  %{"street" => "elsewhere", "country" => "poland"},
]}
```

which is turned with:

```
User
|> Repo.get!(id)
|> Repo.preload(:addresses) # Only required when updating data
|> Ecto.Changeset.cast(params, [])
|> Ecto.Changeset.cast_assoc(:addresses, with: &MyApp.Address.changeset/2)
```

As you see, input JSON data structure has key `"addresses"`, which are then cast as `:addresses`

So your data should have the next structure:

```
%{
  name: "Test", 
  username: "test", 
  credential: %{
    email: "test@here.com", 
    password: "12345678"
  }
}
```

Of course, this is not what you like to have in your registration process!

So, you have two solutions here:

- Throw away all this *Credential* staff, and keep it simple with inside registration changeset.
- Build an association manually - with `build_assoc` or `put_assoc`

Comment: This makes sense, I am following the **programming phoenix 1.4** book. Have a look here [not my code] (https://github.com/chriseyre2000/rumbl_1_4/blob/master/lib/rumbl/accounts/user.ex), as you said `:credential` is empty but I find it hard to believe that the book is wrong.

Comment: Look here - on the template: https://github.com/chriseyre2000/rumbl_1_4/blob/master/lib/rumbl_web/templates/user/new.html.eex. As you see, it has `<%= inputs_for f, :credential, fn cf -> %>`. So the payload when this form is submitted will be like in the initial answer

Comment: me being careless was more probable :)

Answer (score 0):

Enclose your email and password inputs with the `inputs_for/4` function.

```
<%= inputs_for f, :credential, fn cf -> %>
   <%= email_input cf, :email %>
   <%= password_input cf, :password %>
<% end %>
```

It will preload the credentials for you. [Here's the link](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_html/Phoenix.HTML.Form.html#inputs_for/4)